# Is there any way by which I can separately find class using Jquery for each element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

my code is :-

```
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) 

    {
    $('.user_list').append('<li><input type="button" class="user'+ i + '"/></li>');
    }
```

which gives output:-

```
<li><input type="button" class="user_1" /><li>
<li><input type="button" class="user_2" /><li>
<li><input type="button" class="user_3" /><li>
<li><input type="button" class="user_4" /><li>
```

can you tell me what code to write so that when j-query runs and i click any one the buttons and get the corresponding id for the buttons

Comment: I don't see id in your example, do you mean class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get the class

```
$("input[type='button']").click(function() {
   alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/esYAh/

Comment: @Mr. Sahil Grover it does what you asked, I don't see something wrong

Comment: check again it is creating buttons when we click the CREATE_USERS BUTTON but after that clicking on any new generated button there is no alert message showing the class...... of new generated buttons namely USER1 USER2 USER3 ......

Answer (score 1):

to alert id...

> $(function(){

```
 $("input").click(function(){

       alert($this.attr('id'));

 });
```

});

But you have not set id of any of the buttons, so it'll alert with blank message.

Answer (score 0):

You mean class probably

```
$(function(){
    $("input").click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/67e1b/2)